# Read properties file from java class in Grails

Tags: java, grails, properties

i put the urls.properties in conf folder and in src/java folder, but when i want to read this file from java class in grails project, i get an error: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: urls.properties (The system cannot find the file specified)`.

I try read this file with this code:

```
io = new FileInputStream("urls.properties");
prop.load(io);
url = prop.getProperty(urlName);
```

what is wrong and why i get this error? I have a conf parameter in Config.groovy as

```
grails.config.locations = ["classpath:urls.properties"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this chapter in the manual for information about loading external config files:
http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/single.html#configExternalized

After having specified a property file with grails.config.locations, the properties are loaded   automatically when your application is started so they should already be accessible by in the grailsApplication.config object like this:

```
def grailsApplication // Injects the grailsApplication object to your service/controller
...
grailsApplication.config.myproperty
```

Read more here about how to access config properties:
http://grails.org/doc/2.3.7/guide/conf.html

What you are trying to do with your code is to load a file from the current working directory and probably this file does not exists there. Hence the error code.

EDIT

If you want to load a file that exist in the classpath you should load it as a resource instead. Like this:

```
        InputStream is = MyClass.class.getResourceAsStream("urls.properties");
```

...where MyClass is a class which is located in the same package as urls.properties. Don't forget to check if the stream **is** is null, since it will be if it fails to load the resource.

Comment: but how i can read this params from Java class, not from Groovy class?

Comment: Ah, so that is what the problem is all about. If you want to make it the complicated way, see this blog post: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=1017

Comment: Se my edit for how to load a file from a resource in java. This might be a quicker solution.